# streamlit website don't show plot and metric

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, streamlit

I coded a Streamlit website with plot and metric but it doesn't work.

```
import streamlit as st
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

st.title("website")
st.metric(label="velocity", value=23, delta="-1")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(np.arange(10), np.arange(10)**2)
st.pyplot(fig)
```

I tried to use line_chart() instead for plot but it also didn't work.
Did i do something wrong? Can someone help me please?